# Is operator B closed?

Tags: functional-analysis

Hi I have the following problem:

> Let $X=C([0,1])$ with the $||\cdot||_\infty$-norm.
>   $$A:D(A)\subset X\rightarrow X, Au:=u' , D(A)=C^1([0,1])$$
>   $$B:D(B)\subset X\rightarrow X, Bu:=u' , D(B)=C^2([0,1])$$
>   i) Show: $\overline{D(A)}=X$
>
> ii) Is A closed?
>
> iii) Is B closed?

I already showed i) and A is closed. I guess B is not closed but I can't find a proper counterexample. Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried to find a sequence $\{ f_n \}$ of $C^2$ functions such that $f_n'$ and $f_n$ converge uniformly to $f'$ and $f$, where $f$ is a $C^1$ function that is not in $C^2$?